# Ruby and MS Dynamics CRM Authentication

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm attempting to access MS CRM that's exposed via IFD, and I'm having authentication issues.

The SOAP endpoint is behind NTLM, which I've been able to access. The problem is, I'm getting 401 responses when passing requests like the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <Execute xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/CrmDiscoveryService">
            <Request xsi:type="RetrieveCrmTicketRequest">
                <OrganizationName>#{CRM_CONFIG[:org_name]}</OrganizationName>
                <UserId>#{CRM_CONFIG[:username]}</UserId>
                <Password>#{CRM_CONFIG[:password]}</Password>
            </Request>
        </Execute>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Is there any way of debugging this on the server? Any logs I can check to get a more meaningful error message?

I'm also getting a 401 when attempting the following request (this time to the CrmService.asmx endpoint):

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">
  <soap:Header>
    <CrmAuthenticationToken xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices\">
      <AuthenticationType xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/CoreTypes\">2</AuthenticationType>
      <OrganizationName xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/CoreTypes\">#{CRM_CONFIG[:org_name]}</OrganizationName>
      <CallerId xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/CoreTypes\">#{TOUCH}</CallerId>
    </CrmAuthenticationToken>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <RetrieveMultiple xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices\">
      <query xmlns:q1=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2006/Query\" xsi:type=\"q1:QueryExpression\">
        <q1:EntityName>contact</q1:EntityName>
      </query>
    </RetrieveMultiple>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem was a misunderstanding of the setup:

When using NTLM, Active Directory authentication is used, meaning that the CrmAuthenticationToken should have looked like this:

```
<CrmAuthenticationToken xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices\">
  <AuthenticationType xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/CoreTypes\">0</AuthenticationType>
  <OrganizationName xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/CoreTypes\">#{CRM_CONFIG[:org_name]}</OrganizationName>
</CrmAuthenticationToken>
```

Note that the CallerId element isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on server side tracing [by hand](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907490) or with a [tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benlec/archive/2008/03/04/crmdiagtool4-for-microsoft-crm-4-0-has-been-released.aspx). Look for trace files in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Trace. For easy trace file viewing I recommend using [CRM Trace Log Viewer](http://www.stunnware.com/crm2/topic.aspx?id=TraceLogViewer).

There are lots of articles about how to [call Dynamics CRM web services from JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150838.aspx). I can imagine those will come in handy.

In my experience, two more tools will also come handy, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to trace http requests and responses and [SoapUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/) for web service testing and debugging.

Also note, that Dynamics CRM 2011 will come with REST based services in addition to SOAP based, which will greatly simplify CRM web service usage from non-.net products.